# Mobile phone app specific term — How would one say "press" or "tap"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

For example, move a game piece and use it to tap on another game piece.
So far, I think it is likely *antasten* most likely (I have consulted dict.leo.org). I would be grateful if a native German speaker or at least someone with experience with application localization would confirm or correct this thought.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Tap* and *press* describe two different actions, in my opinion. The former means gently hit against the piece and then withdraw, which I would translate with *klopfen* or *antippen*. The latter means "apply a constant pressure", which I would translate with *drücken*.

Comment: The whole expression would be "auf den Spielstein klopfen" or "den Spielstein antippen".

Comment: I have to ask my son, the wordings change daily for these purposes..

Comment: Yes. That makes more sense. Ich denke "auf den Spielstein klopfen" klingt am besten. Danke sehr.

Comment: I've never heard "klopfen" with touch screens. "Klopfen" may also imply a few hard knocks, like on a door, which doesn't sound like what one would do on a smart phone.

Comment: "Antippen" or maybe "berühren" (touch) is better.  You don't knock (anklopfen) a screen

Comment: thanks all for the comments. is for a game type context so not the typical app instruction type thing ...you are right would not want to actually knock on the screen literally... more like knock on a door displayed on the screen itself.. all in all probably "den Spielstein antippen" as was also mentioned in first answer maybe is going to be the way to go in the context of the particular game. Ich danke Ihnen noch einmals.

Answer (score 3):

As someone who plays mobile games, I would recommend *antippen* or *berühren*. But *berühren* may sound weird if used repeatedly.

I would advise against *klopfen* unless you want a series of 2 or 3 short touches (like knocking with a finger), then it would be the term of my choice.

I would avoid *antasten* it sounds weird, and I never heard it in the context of mobile applications.